# .NET MAUI publish issue when referencing CLASS LIBRARY - project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for "class library framework"

Tags: visual-studio, maui, publish, .net-standard, .net-8.0

Have been struggling with this for a while and all workarounds that works for other people DOESN'T work for me.

When I Publish a .Net MAUI app, I get the following error.

[image]

```
1>Assets file 'C:\Users\potgi\source\repos\Stax_MAUI\StaxDAL\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 'netstandard2.0'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'netstandard2.0' in the TargetFrameworks for your project.
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish completed at 19:08 and took 18.535 seconds ==========
========== Package: 0 succeeded, 1 failed ===========
```

I have 3 projects in my solution:

1. .NET MAUI project
2. .NET Standard 2.0 Class Library Project
3. Web API project (Don't think this is relevant to publish issue)

[image]

1. .NET MAUI project .csproj
   This project references the .NET Standard Class Lib with the shared Models. The Web API project also references this project for the models.

[image]

[image]

2. .NET Standard 2.0 Class Library Project .csproj

[image]

Cofiguration seettings
[image]

Now the step by step PUBLISH process:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The Publish Profile
[image]

Visual Studio Information:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022
Version 17.9.2
VisualStudio.17.Release/17.9.2+34622.214
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.8.09037

Installed Version: Community

Visual C++ 2022   00482-90000-00000-AA845
Microsoft Visual C++ 2022

ADL Tools Service Provider   1.0
This package contains services used by Data Lake tools

ASA Service Provider   1.0

ASP.NET and Web Tools   17.9.197.37128
ASP.NET and Web Tools

Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0   17.9.197.37128
Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0

Azure Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio   2.6.5000.0
Microsoft Azure Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio

Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools   17.9.197.37128
Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools

Azure Stream Analytics Tools for Visual Studio   2.6.5000.0
Microsoft Azure Stream Analytics Tools for Visual Studio

C# Tools   4.9.0-3.24121.1+a98c90d56455379836dd5c845b35fa932b00cfa3
```

Can anyone help me, please.... I have tries .Net 6.0, .Net8 and .Net MAUI Class Libraries as well, but I get the same error (The target framework just change).
Publish worked fine until a Visual Studio update (Can't remember witch one, but it was about the time of the .Net 8 release.

Comment: *I have tries .Net 6.0, .Net8 and .Net MAUI Class Libraries as well, but I get the same error (The target framework just change).*  You mean you have tried to changed `NET Standard 2.0 Class Library Project` to `.Net 6.0, .Net8 and .Net MAUI Class Libraries` like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AI24M.png)?

Answer (score 0):

> I have 3 projects in my solution:
>
> 1. .NET MAUI project
> 2. .NET Standard 2.0 Class Library Project
> 3. Web API project (Don't think this is relevant to publish issue)
>
> NET MAUI project .csproj This project references the .NET Standard
> Class Lib with the shared Models. The Web API project also references
> this project for the models.

I found a similar issue on Maui Github: [Unable to archive app if it references a .NET Standard 2.0 class library
#11906](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/11906) and this [comment](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/11906#issuecomment-1738127621) in the issue:

> Has anyone got a fix/workaround for this? It seems incredible that
> such a showstopping issue remains unaddressed. It's trivial to
> reproduce:
>
> 1. In Visual Studio Mac, create blank MAUI app.
> 2. Add new class library project targeting .NET Standard 2.0 to
>    solution.
> 3. Add a project reference to the class library project to the MAUI
>    project.
>
> Archive for Publishing now fails.

One difference is that he is VS Mac. But he hasn't returned to reply since then.

You can report the problem on [issue of MAUI GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues). This may be related to Regarding .NET 8, currently it still has many issues.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workable workaround [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Assets-file-projectassetsjson-doesnt-/10461984#T-ND10607181)